# nscollection view using cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

i i tried to integrate the icon Collection sample of apple docs in my application but it throws error:

```
@interface MyViewController : NSViewController <NSCollectionViewDelegate>
```

shows error in my project as 
`"Cannot find protocol declaration for NSCollectionViewDelegate"`

please help somebody.

Comment: Are you targeting Mac OS 10.5? `NSCollectionViewDelegate` is Mac OS 10.6+ only.

Comment: no i am targeting Mac OS 10.6 only

Answer (score 0):

You need to #import the file where that protocol is defined into the header where you declare your class.

Comment: i have already included appkit framework and also tried to import the class but still shows the same error

Comment: I am not sure but I think you are using the duplicate protocol declaration and yes, I'd say the circular import of the .h files is the problem. Instead of importing, just add a forward declaration of the class(es) you need to reference to the file. Or try to #include'ing it instead of #import'ing it. I hope this helps